# Problem with Magento Templates

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

When I use this code in layout Everything is good

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/chocolatebox/chocolatebox.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><stylesheet>chocolatebox/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>chocolatebox/chocolatebox.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

But I want to apply to my template using blocks. When i doing this my template is destroying

```
<?php
class Chocolate_Box_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{

    public function _beforeToHtml(){
//       /die();
       $this->setTemplate("chocolatebox/chocolatebox.phtml");
    }
}
```

config

```
<blocks>
        <chocolatebox>
            <class>Chocolate_Box_Block</class>
        </chocolatebox>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>Chocolate_Box_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view>Chocolate_Box_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

Comment: could you please look for error messages, increase the error output and activate dev mode?
Also could you look at which line the html output stops and show this line of the template/php class?

Comment: I'd be surprised if the *`chocolatebox/chocolatebox.phtml`* template is being set correctly by this layout XML - the `<action />` tag needs to either be a child of a `block` or `<reference />` tag OR it needs to have a `block=""` attribute declaration.

Comment: Also, minor points (not the issue): `_beforeToHtml()` should be `protected` not `public` scope, and it should `return` either the parent or `$this`.

Comment: And in conclusion, try instantiating your class directly in a [workbench script](https://gist.github.com/benmarks/4532434) to see if there are unrelated issues.

Answer (score 1):

The `setTemplate` should be called from the `_construct` function. As Ben Marks commented it should work from `_beforeHtml` tho. refactor the block class to look something like this:

```
<?php
class Chocolate_Box_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{

    public function _construct(){
       parent::_construct();
       $this->setTemplate("chocolatebox/chocolatebox.phtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn`t help

Comment: Maybe problem in layout??

Comment: Could be but without any further info I won't be able to help you find the issue

Comment: *"...`_beforeToHtml` will be to late to manipulate the template"* No it's not ;-)

Comment: @benmarks I stand corrected... Wait, shouldn't you be following some kind of seminar at mm14pl?!

Comment: Sitting in Damian's docker presentation at the moment. They pay me to multitask.